# Is there a term for a smart text field that provides a different experience based on the content entered into the text field?

Tags: usability, design-patterns, data

I'm designing an experience that will require a text field to "recognize" content and instantly direct users to different paths from the same point (same text field & CTA) based on the text entered. Entered text will be completely free form (i.e. user generated) so this text field needs to use keywords and keyword combos to recognize what information/path the user is looking for.

EX: One text field to submit questions. Some of those questions are complex and need to direct the user to a flow that allows them to ask a person to provide an in-depth answer. Other questions may just be customer service inquiries that could return a customer service number or even send the user through another flow to perform an action related to their account.

Comment: Not an answer, but is what Steam does similar to what you are mentioning? https://support.steampowered.com/ Not sure what I'd call it... maybe a guided search box? Or some sort of first level of tech support?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is we have a product that starts with a large text field and CTA. It's meant for asking questions of professionals, but we get a large percentage of customer service questions coming through this field despite the clear labeling of said text field (people either don't read or ignore instructions)... search boxes mimicking a CS rep (i.e. nanorep) would only solve for the CS questions, but not for the intended purpose of the product.

I want the text field to recognize the difference b/t the types of questions & produce experiences based on the content.

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding you, StackExchange actually has the same issue. I'm not so sure it is handled perfectly, but when you go here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/ask and type the title, it reminds you to ask questions about the site on Meta (with a link). Maybe a little reminder like that would reduce the load enough to be acceptable? People still ask meta questions on SE sites from time to time, but fortunately there is a mechanism to migrate the few who do this.

Comment: 'Google search window'

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me, we are talking about **Search**, specifically '**smart**' search. As a result, you should continue to use the qualifier 'smart', but consider calling your text box a search field.

Your description of the functionality reminds me of Google's smart search results. For example, searching the answer to a Mathematics question or currency conversion simply gives you the answer directly.
'Smart' search article: http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57489395-93/google-exposes-smart-results-in-search/

Answer (score 1):

*Natural language search*. You may also call this *intelligent search*. But your engine should better be pretty smart, otherwise you will get laughed at. People making features like this usually give them *a human name*, like *Eliza*. For user service, companies have built their *Eva* (Free), *Clara* (Fnac)… Often they are not very successful. — And I am polite. ;-)